# Swift - Block off utilisation of a button

Tags: swift

I want to stop the utilisation of a button when a countdown is over.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var scoreTemporaire : Int = 0


    @IBOutlet weak var afficheurScore: UILabel!

    @IBAction func boutonPlus(sender: UIButton) {

            scoreTemporaire = scoreTemporaire + 1
            afficheurScore.text = "\(scoreTemporaire)"

        }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //calling the wait function
        self.callForWait()
    }

    func callForWait(){
        //setting the delay time 60secs.
        let delay = 12 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            //call the method which have the steps after delay.
            self.stepsAfterDelay()
        }
    }


    func stepsAfterDelay(){
        let score = scoreTemporaire
        afficheurScore.text = "\(score)"

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

When the delay has passed, The score appairs on the Label (afficheurScore) but when you reclick on the button (boutonPlus), scoreTemporaire go up. I want to stop the possibility to touch the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set

```
myButton.enabled = false
```

You should connect your button from storyboard to your code, in the same way you actually did with the `UILabel`.
The code above disables the button.